# Array of Strings MIPS

Tags: string, loops, assembly, mips

So my program is running into an infinite loop when printing words:

It's printing the first character of my array, but it's not incrementing to the next character. I'm not sure what exactly to do at this point: adding i * 4 + 1 ran into an exception and i * 4 only prints the first character. Suggestions?

```
#Prints original string
#Prints each word in string
#Prints word count for each string
#Prints final concatenated word count

.data

phrases:        .word string1
                .word string2
                .word string3
                .word string4
                .word string5
                .word string6
                .word string7
                .word string8
                .word string9
                .word string10
                .word string11
                .word string12

numPhrases:
                .word 12

string1:        .asciiz "Four-score"
string2:        .asciiz "and seven years"
string3:        .asciiz "ago, our"
string4:        .asciiz "fathers"
string5:        .asciiz "brought forth on"
string6:        .asciiz "this continent a"
string7:        .asciiz "new nation, "
string8:        .asciiz "conceived in liberty"
string9:        .asciiz "and dedicated to the"
string10:       .asciiz "proposition"
string11:       .asciiz "that all men are"
string12:       .asciiz "created equal."

# Your code goes below this line

        origString:     .asciiz "The original string:\n"
        words:          .asciiz "Words found in the string:\n"
        wordCount:      .asciiz "Word count is now "
        finalCount:     .asciiz "Final word count is "
        newline:        .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:

        # Function prologue
        addiu   $sp, $sp, -24   # allocate stack space -- default of 24 here
        sw      $fp, 0($sp)     # save caller's frame pointer
        sw      $ra, 4($sp)     # save return address
        addiu   $fp, $sp, 20    # setup main's frame pointer


        #Initial loop conditions
        la      $t0, numPhrases
        lw      $s0, 0($t0)     #$s0 = numPhrases

        la      $s1, phrases    #$s1 now equals arr of strings

        addi    $s2, $zero, 0   #i = 0, loop each char of a string
        addi    $s3, $zero, 0   #j = 0, loop each address of phrases
        addi    $t2, $zero, 0   #word count = 0

 loopPhrases:
        #for (j < phrases.length)
        #       print phrases[j];
        #j++

        #exit condition
        slt     $t1, $s3, $s0           #$t1 = j < numPhrases
        beq     $t1, $zero, endPhrases  #if j < numPhrases, end

        #loop body
        #print original string
        la      $a0, origString
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

        add     $s4, $s1, $s3   #$address of phrases[j]
        lw      $s5, 0($s4)     #$s5 = phrases[j]
        addi    $a0, $s5, 0
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall                 #print string

        #newline
        la      $a0, newline
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

        #Print words
        la      $a0, words
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

 loopWords:
        #while (charAt(i) != '\n', '\t', or ' '
        #and i < string.length())
        #       print charAt(i)
        #       i++

        #exit condition
        add     $t5, $s2, $s1           #address of string[i]
        lw      $s5, 0($t5)             #string[i]
        beq     $s5, $zero, endWords     #if string[i] == nul, end

        #If whitespace, jump
        addi    $t1, $zero, 9           #$t0 = 9(tab)
        beq     $t0, $t1, nextWord      #$t0 = tab
        addi    $t1, $zero, 10          #$t0 = 10(newline)
        beq     $t0, $t1, nextWord      #$t0 = newline
        addi    $t1, $zero, 32          #$t0 = 32(space)
        beq     $t0, $t1, nextWord      #$t0 = space

        #Print word
        lb      $a0, 0($s5)
        add     $v0, $zero, 11
        syscall

        #i++
        add     $s2, $s2, $s2
        add     $s2, $s2, $s2
        j       loopWords

nextWord:
        la      $a0, newline
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

        addi    $t2, $t2, 1     #wordCount++
        addi    $s2, $s2, 1     #i++
        j       loopWords

endWords:

        #Print word count
        la      $a0, wordCount
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

        la      $a0, 0($t2)
        addi    $v0, $zero, 1
        syscall

        #newlines
        la      $a0, newline
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

        la      $a0, newline
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

        #j++
        addi    $s3, $s3, 4
        j       loopPhrases

endPhrases:

        #Print final count
        la      $a0, finalCount
        addi    $v0, $zero, 4
        syscall

        la      $a0, 0($t2) #word count
        addi    $v0, $zero, 1
        syscall

        done:   #Epilogue for main -- restore stack & frame pointer
        lw      $ra, 4($sp)     #get return address from stack
        lw      $fp, 0($sp)     #restore the caller's frame pointer
        addiu   $sp, $sp, 24    #restore the caller's stackpointer
        jr      $ra             #return to caller's code
```

Comment: _"Nevermind, fixed it"_. In that case you should either post an answer explaining what the solutions is, or close the question.

Comment: increment i++ to move i to the next element
then set do $s5 * 4 to offset for .word so you can read the next element of String[i]